# Submit HTTP Post to Gateway Server?

Tags: mysql, networking, server

What does it mean by submit HTTP Post to Gateway Server? The target server look like this `http://localhost:8155/vxcrm.jsp`

I've seen many PHP tutorials to directly create a new table or modify the existing table in the database to add new data. However, using Gateway, it seems like I do not have to have direct access to the database, not even have to have a MySql user account.

Can somebody explain this? I'm new to computer networking and everything seems intimidating. Please go easy on me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp to understand what get and post requests are all about. The basic difference is that a POST request requires the client to embed query params in the body of the message whereas the params are appended directly to the URL in a GET request.

My best guess is that your gateway server defines certain parameters that allows clients to construct and submit POST requests in order to manipulate data in the mysql database (including creating, deleting, modifying tables). To do any of these tasks, you will need to obtain (from the author of the server) a list of valid params and understand how those params can get help you accomplish your task.

Comment: I think you're right. Here's the list of params listed on their tutorial http://www.voicent.com/tutorials/Call_Center_CRM/Dynamic_Campaigns/Web_Interface_API.php 

Now, I usually use `mysql_connect()`, `mysql_select_db()` and finally `mysql_query(INSERT INTO db_name VALUES())` to communicate with the database. But, how do I query a gateway?

Comment: Skimming through the web interface apis, there are three possible actions you can use - `add`, `get` and `delete`. It appears that there is no interface to directly connect to a database - all queries may be executed on a default, pre-determined database on the server. The server should take care of establishing a connection to the DB and selecting the DB/tables for you. If you wish to query the DB, just send a POST request to the server as action=get&first_name=foo. Similarly, to insert into the DB, you could use `action=add&first_name=foo&last_name=bar&` and so on.